# How to unzip a zip file shared through iTunes from the Application Programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, zip, itunes, nsdocumentdirectory

I need to unzip file synced through itunes in the documents directory programmatically. There are open source frameworks available like ZipArchive and ZipKit but I am not able to use them in the project. Is there a decent tutorial where I can see how to use these frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/samsoffes/ssziparchive).
It is so simple way to unzip file. please read [Readme.markdown](https://github.com/samsoffes/ssziparchive/blob/master/Readme.markdown) (usage).
Simple three lines and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

For ZipKit, you need to use the Better Way of Installing the Framework and follow the Static Library section of the [ZipKit Documentation](https://bitbucket.org/kolpanic/zipkit/wiki/UsingZipKit) because iOS doesn't allow you to use to embed the Frameworks directly. You need to include it as a Static Library.

Alternatively you could use something lightweight like [iZip](http://www.dankrusi.com/page_69653F3334373E40.html)